# Is it possible to redirect the output of a command to one file, but still keep the output echoing on the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

Is it possible to redirect the output of a command to one file, but still keep the output echoing on the terminal?

I want the output to go to a file, but I still want to see it on the terminal (just so I know something is going on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `tee` does what you want:

```
command | tee output.log
```

Comment: The name "tee" aludes a "T"-fork, a splitting of the output in two.

Comment: As @deagh wrote the `-a` flag is needed when you need to append the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "tee" i.e.

```
ls -ltr | tee -a mylog.log
```